# Like Java, should Object.call be the first call in Javascript constructor too?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, constructor

I was writing some OOP code in Javascript and the design of the inheritance raised a question. Like Java should super constructor call be the first line in subclass constructor in Javascript?

```
var Effect = function (container, height, width) {};

var XEffect = function (container, height, width, resource) {
    Effect.call(container, height, width ); // really necessary to be first line?
};
```

Comment: It should be, if the first thing the constructor to do is running the other constructor. If that's not what you want, then it shouldn't be. Does the `Effect` constructor perform operations that are critical for the `XEffect` instances? If so, call it.

Comment: `.call` in JS doesn't do what you seem to think it does. `.call` invokes a function with the first parameter bound as `this` inside the function and all remaining parameters passed in as arguments. It has nothing to do with inheritance per se, though it can be used in inheritance patterns if you pass in `this` as your `this` value (confused yet?).

Comment: It should be `Effect.call(this, container, height, width);`

Answer (score 0):

To quote Douglas Crockford: "JavaScript has a class-free object system in which objects inherit properties directly from other objects. This is really powerful, but it is unfamiliar to classically trained programmers. If you attempt to apply classical design patterns directly to JavaScript, you will be frustrated. But if you learn to work with JavaScript's prototypal nature, your efforts will be rewarded."

Check out [Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) for how inheritance is handled in JavaScript.

In your code snippet, `Effect.call(container, height, width);` would simply evaluate as `undefined` unless you specifically define it before hand. To call the functionality of your `Effect` function, you would simply invoke it as `Effect()`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't like the object-oriented systems implemented in languages like Java and C++. My favourite object-oriented system is that implemented by the [Fortress programming language](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/samth/fortress-spec.pdf). For example, consider the following Fortress code taken from the famous blog post [Why Object-Oriented Languages Need Tail Calls](http://www.eighty-twenty.org/2011/10/01/oo-tail-calls/) written by [Guy Steele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_L._Steele%2C_Jr.) (a.k.a. The Great Quux):

```
trait IntSet
  getter isEmpty(): Boolean = false
  adjoin(x: ZZ): IntSet = AdjoinObject(self, x)
  union(other: IntSet): IntSet = UnionObject(self, other)
  contains(y: ZZ): Boolean
end

object AdjoinObject(s: IntSet, x: ZZ) extends IntSet
  contains(y: ZZ) = (y = x) OR: s.contains(y)
end

object UnionObject(s1: IntSet, s2: IntSet) extends IntSet
  isEmpty: Boolean = s1.isEmpty AND s2.isEmpty
  contains(y: ZZ) = s1.contains(y) OR: s2.contains(y)
end

object EmptyObject extends IntSet
  isEmpty: Boolean = true
  contains(y: ZZ) = false
end
```

Object definitions in Fortress introduce object constructors. These constructors may either be nullary (e.g. `EmptyObject`) or parameterized (e.g. `AdjoinObject` and `UnionObject`).

Traits are similar to [abstract base classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type). Hence, you can't create an instance of a trait directly. Instead you need to create a concrete object that implements the interface of the trait.

Note that in this scenario you never need to call a superclass constructor because there is no superclass constructor. All the superclasses (traits) are abstract. They have no state and hence they do not need to be initialized. The state of the object is encapsulated within the object constructor. This is important because it promotes [data abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)#Data_abstraction), an important property of object-oriented programs.

#### So how would this Fortress code look in JavaScript?

There are many ways to write object-oriented code in JavaScript. However, the following Fortress-style object-oriented JavaScript code is my favorite:

```js
class IntSet {
    get isEmpty() { return false; }
    adjoin(x) { return AdjoinObject(this, x); }
    union(other) { return UnionObject(this, other); }
    contains(y) { throw new Error("Abstract method invocation"); }
}

const AdjoinObject = (s, x) => new class extends IntSet {
    contains(y) { return y === x || s.contains(y); }
}

const UnionObject = (s1, s2) => new class extends IntSet {
    get isEmpty() { return s1.isEmpty && s2.isEmpty; }
    contains(y) { return s1.contains(y) || s2.contains(y); }
}

const EmptyObject = new class extends IntSet {
    get isEmpty() { return true; }
    contains(y) { return false; }
}

const Empty = EmptyObject;

const example = Empty.adjoin(1).adjoin(2).union(Empty.adjoin(3));

console.log(example.contains(1)); // true
console.log(example.contains(2)); // true
console.log(example.contains(3)); // true
console.log(example.contains(4)); // false
```

Uncomplicated [solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) object-oriented programming in JavaScript. In addition, you do not need to worry about superclass constructors.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what the Effect constructor does.

**The object and its prototype chain are already set up by the time you reach the first line of code in the constructor**. That is to say, before XEffect's constructor is set up, `this` already exists, and its `__proto__` is already set to `XEffect.prototype`. So your object is already an `XEffect`, which inherits from `Effect`.

**However, by this point, none of the code in `Effect` or `XEffect` has been run yet**. The `XEffect` code will be run, since it's part of the constructor function, but **`Effect` won't be run unless you tell JavaScript to do so**. If you wish to call `Effect` explicitly, you can. As you described, `Effect.call(this, ...)` or `Effect.apply(this, [])` are probably the ways you'd want to do that.

**The catch is that `Effect` runs when you tell it to run: no later, no sooner**. If `Effect` writes to some properties of the object, and then code later in `XEffect` writes to those same properties, `XEffect` wins: those are the values that the object will have when its over. If you reverse this order -write to properties inside `XEffect`, then call `Effect`, which writes to those same properties- then `Effect` wins.

**If you're used to writing in a "class-based" style, then calling `Effect` first is probably closest to what you want**. It writes to the object's properties, and then `XEffect` (potentially) overwrites them. But you don't *have* to do it that way, if you have some reason that you want `Effect` to win.